# How can I disable Quick Access TextField in Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, rcp

today I changed my Eclipse IDE from 3.7 to 4.2 and my plugin-project has a new feature in the Statusbar of the UI called QuickAccess. But I dont need it, so how can I disable this feature, because the position of my button bar has changed...

Comment: That "QuickAccess" feature should not be visible by default with the most recent 4.x version (starting with 4.4 M5). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21245059/6309)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Help --> Install New Software
https://raw.github.com/atlanto/eclipse-4.x-filler/master/pdt_tools.eclipse-4.x-filler.update/

Install that Plugin and Restart the Eclipse. Quick Access automatically hide.
or else you have an option to hide Window --> Hide Quick Access.

Answer (score 4):

For all who have the same problem, it seems that this new feature is hardcoded and can't be disabled :/ https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=362420

Comment: They've started discourage me to this IDE

Comment: I've "peeking" on 4.x releases, and NONE so far made me happy. I needed to "hack" the 3.x releases to change some RCP behaviors, and not going to do the same with 4... The Quick Access should not be hard-coded.

Comment: Go to Help --> Install New Software https://raw.github.com/atlanto/eclipse-4.x-filler/master/pdt_tools.eclipse-4.x-filler.update/

Install that Plugin and Restart the Eclipse. Quick Access automatically hide. or else you have an option to hide Window --> Hide Quick Access.

Answer (score 1):

[Lars Vogel](http://blog.vogella.com/author/vogella/) just reported in his blog post "[Porting Eclipse 3.x RCP application to Eclipse 4.4 – now without QuickAccess box](http://blog.vogella.com/2014/01/20/porting-eclipse-3-x-rcp-application-to-eclipse-4-4-now-without-quickaccess-box/)":

[Bug 411821 ([`QuickAccess`] Contribute `SearchField` through a fragment or other means)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=411821) 
is now solved.
Thanks to René Brandstetter:

> If a RCP app doesn't provide the QuickAccess element in its model, than it will not be visible. So the default is no QuickAcces, easy enough? :)

See the [commit 839ee2](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/commit/?id=839ee2d7fec814e08fdd1d5461d1779684e44aea) for more details

> Provide the "`QuickAccess`" via a e4 application model fragment inside of the "`org.eclipse.ui.ide.application`".
>   This removes the "`QuickAccess`" search field from every none "`org.eclipse.ui.ide.application`".

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a post](http://andydunkel.net/eclipse/java/2013/08/20/eclipse-rcp-remove-quick-access-from-toolbar.html) that shows a way to hide it with CSS.  Verified with Eclipse 4.3

Answer (score 0):

You could also hide it and make it work comparable to how it used to work in Eclipse3.7: when  user presses ctrl+3 Quick Access functionality pops up (In Eclipse4.3 the ctrl+3 shortcut is still available).

Example of code you could add to your implementation of WorkbenchWindowAdvisor (for Eclipse4.3 rcp application)

```
private IHandlerActivation quickAccessHandlerActivation;

@Override
public void postWindowOpen() {
    hideQuickAccess();
}

private void hideQuickAccess() {
    IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    setQuickAccessVisible(window, false);

    final IHandlerService service = (IHandlerService) window.getService(IHandlerService.class);
    quickAccessHandlerActivation = service.activateHandler(QUICK_ACCESS_COMMAND_ID, new CustomQuickAccessHandler());
}

private void setQuickAccessVisible(IWorkbenchWindow window, boolean visible) {
    if (window instanceof WorkbenchWindow) {
        MTrimBar topTrim = ((WorkbenchWindow) window).getTopTrim();

        for (MTrimElement element : topTrim.getChildren()) {
            if (QUICK_ACCESS_ELEMENT_ID.equals(element.getElementId())) {
                element.setVisible(visible);
                if (visible) {
                    Composite control = (Composite) element.getWidget();
                    control.getChildren()[0].addFocusListener(new QuickAccessFocusListener());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

private class QuickAccessFocusListener implements FocusListener {

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        //not interested
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        ((Control) e.widget).removeFocusListener(this);
        hideQuickAccess();
    }

}

private class CustomQuickAccessHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
        final IHandlerService service = (IHandlerService) window.getService(IHandlerService.class);
        setQuickAccessVisible(window, true);
        if (quickAccessHandlerActivation != null) {
            service.deactivateHandler(quickAccessHandlerActivation);

            try {
                return service.executeCommand(QUICK_ACCESS_COMMAND_ID, null);
            } catch (NotDefinedException e) {

            } catch (NotEnabledException e) {

            } catch (NotHandledException e) {

            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```