# Eclipse not showing search bar

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

Just installed Eclipse Version: **Neon.1a Release (4.6.1) on Ubuntu 16.10** but its not showing the usual search box in the top right which can be used to search the whole software.

It came handy to directly open some commands without navigating through menus. Anyone know where is it gone?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to get it. Some times this will not work on Linux, then set focus on any view/editor in the current perspective then try.

Refer this bug this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=362420) and this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=497726). Refer this [How can I disable Quick Access TextField in Eclipse RCP Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296122/how-can-i-disable-quick-access-textfield-in-eclipse-rcp-application) and this post [Remove "Quick Access" entry in Eclipse Juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549283/remove-quick-access-entry-in-eclipse-juno)

Comment: Yes. You can hide or show quick access text box in tool bar. Refer [this](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.4/eclipse-news-part1.php) and [this](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/platform.php) links. You can also toggle toolbar visibility in `Window > Appearance > Hide/Show toolbar`